# Django - form with foreignkey that refers to a non-primary key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django model:

```
class ObservationMedia(models.Model):
    observation = models.ForeignKey(Observation)    
    audio_file = AudioFileField   ( upload_to=audio_dir, blank=True, null=True )
    photo_file = models.ImageField( upload_to=img_dir,   blank=True, null=True )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "obsv-media "+str(self.pk)
```

where Observation is:

```
class Observation(GUIDModel):  
    guid = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
    # many more fields here
```

Is it possible to have a `ModelForm` of `ObservationMedia` where the value passed to `Observation` is not its primary key but the `guid` field? The solution I thought of is to make `guid` primary key. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: you can override the __init__ method of your model form and set the value of observation field to use GUID.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following, It's not tested just what i could think of at this moment.

```
class ObservationMediaForm(ModelForm):
    """ Observation Media Model Form """

    class Meta:
        model = models.ObservationMedia
        fields = ('observation', 'audio_file', 'photo_file')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ObservationMediaForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['observation'].initial = models.Observation.objects.get(pk=self.instance.observation).guid
```

Comment: That's a good solution. As it stands, it raises a DoesNotExist error on the last line, which I don't really understand. Any idea?

Comment: try printing or logging self.instance.observation and see if it's the `id` or the object itself. if it's the object you can directly do `.initial = self.instance.observation.guid`

Comment: `self.instance.observation` is also returning a `DoesNotExist` error. It's strange because if I `dir(self.instance)`, `observation` is there.

Comment: how are you initiating the form ? are you passing in an instance ? or is it a blank form to create a new `ObservationMedia` object ?

Comment: blank form to create a new ``ObservationMedia`` object.

Comment: in that case the code under above `__init__` method is not being executed as it does not have an instance, you need to pass in an instance like `form = ObservationMediaForm(instance = ObservationMediaInstance)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is `to_field_name` ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name))

Then you will have something like this:

```
class ObservationMediaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    observation = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Observation.objects.all(), to_field_name='guid')
    # ... other fields

    class Meta:
        model = Observation
        fields = (
            'observation',
            ...
        )
```

Now observation field form will match against provided `guid` values.

Downside is that you will also have to set the initial value in case of an update.